# Ruby on Rails errors while creating new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm having some issues with starting a new project. When I try to create a new project after `run bundle install` I get the following:

```
C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/ge
nerators/app_base.rb:330:in ``': No such file or directory - ""C:/Program Files/
Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe"" "C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/
bundler-1.7.8/bin/bundle" install (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8
/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:330:in `block in bundle_command'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.8/
lib/bundler.rb:236:in `block in with_clean_env'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.8/
lib/bundler.rb:223:in `with_original_env'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.8/
lib/bundler.rb:229:in `with_clean_env'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8
/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:329:in `bundle_command'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8
/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:344:in `run_bundle'
        from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/li
b/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/li
b/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/li
b/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/li
b/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8
/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8
/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8
/bin/rails:9:in `'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/bin/rails:23:in `load'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/bin/rails:23:in `'
```

My version of Ruby is 2.1.5 and Rails version 4.1.8. I have Rails installed manually, but when I used the Rails installer I had the same issue.

Comment: When doing rails development on windows you should use x86 instead of x64. Have you installed rubydevkit?

Comment: I changed to x86 now and I still have the problem. Yes, I have installed devkit. As I mentioned, the same happens when I use rails installer which is supposed to install everything.

Comment: you should be typing `bundle install` not `run bundle install`

Comment: Update the message with you new errors

Comment: It's important that you take time to correctly format your question so its readable. Unreadable questions distract and deter the possible answerers which means you get less help. In other words, the more effort you put into your question, the more likely you'll get help.

Comment: I am not typing that. After I try to create a new rails project by using rails new it stops at "run bundle install" and shows the errors I pasted above.

Comment: Thanks the Tin Man I will keep that in mind the next time and thanks for editing the post, so it looks better now

Comment: have you a file `C:/Program Files/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe`?